# Fetch POST from JS and read response from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm collecting data in a form and 
calling this js:

```
fetch('process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
}).then(response => alert( response ) );
```

process.php gets called correctly; i perform my ops and then i try to return a confirmation message, or a failure message like this:

```
 echo json_encode('Upload completato correttamente');
```

But i can't get the message to show in the alert:
i only get "[object promise]" and playing around with the response i can't seem to read the message.

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch function return Promise <pending>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656223/fetch-function-return-promise-pending)

Comment: What's the point of `json_encode` if you're just intending to return a plain string? Don't bother with JSON, just return it as text.

Comment: @ADyson if i return plain text, the alert says "[object Response]"

Comment: Oh boy, there’s still people who use `alert` as a debugging tool these days? Log this stuff to console, then you can inspect it there and see what _kind_ of object it actually is.

Comment: @MauroSampietro because it _is_ an object, not just text. The response to a HTTP request is not just the body text alone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: I want to keep things as simple as possible to get a quick answer. I know the resturn object it's not just the plain text. But how to get to payload message?

Comment: Assuming you changed `echo json_encode('Upload completato correttamente');` to `echo 'Upload completato correttamente';` in the PHP, then `fetch('process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData }).then(response => response.text() ).then(result=>{
 alert(result);
});` should do it. There are lots of examples of this kind of thing online. Here's a simple demo (using a different endpoint, but the principle is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/1r79evup/)

Comment: thanks, problem solved thanks to all of the advises console etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in the php code i could spot via console.
It was preventing the following correct code to work correctly:

```
fetch('process.php', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
  .then(response => response.text() )
  .then(result=>{ alert(result); });
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

you need to parsing your result like this

```
fetch('process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
}).then(response => response.json() ).then(result=>{
 alert(result);
});
```

hope this work

Comment: If i try this, reach response.json() is not even called

Comment: in your browser, right click on your browser and open network tab, and then reload your page, you'll see your fetch request, select that request, in the right side, open response tab, you'll see your response. make sure you get response what you want

Comment: or just console.log() that result, and see what result you get

Comment: I get a ReadableStream i don't know how to read :(

Comment: please add sreenshot of your console.log result

Comment: thanks, problem solved thanks to all of the advises console etc.