# How to get the result from a pending Promise? [[PromiseResult]]

Tags: javascript, promise

I make fetch to server:

```
reader.onload = async function (e) {
(...)
     await fetch('/processImg', {
                    method: 'GET',
                }).then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res.text()); 
                })
                }).then(function (data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                });
(...)
}
```

And I get the following result: 
Promise {< pending >}
__ proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "done"
How can I get the 'done' value from [[PromiseResult]]? If needed I can provide more code (from server too)

Comment: `res.text()` returns a promise itself. You need to wait for that one too with `.then`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch function return Promise <pending>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656223/fetch-function-return-promise-pending) - the only difference is that they get `json`, not `text`.

Comment: Related: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) | [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)